# Disable extensions in VScode from command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd

Seems like some extension badly affects to run Vscode.
When I try to open Vscode there is "Window no longer responding"
**How to disable Vscode extensions through cmd?**

Answer (score 20):

You can disable extensions via [command line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_core-cli-options) with the `--disable-extensions` flag

```
code --disable-extensions
```

Comment: This command would disable all installed extensions, so what should i do to disable a specific one?

Comment: @JwJJJJ there currently is no way to disable a specific one with the available commands provided. You could get a list of all installed extensions `--list-extensions` and in your terminal of choice remove the one in question and then use `--install-extension`  for the filtered list items but that's beyond the scope of this question

Comment: Does the opposite exist — to enable them? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_enable-an-extension doesn't list a method.

Comment: Correct it does not sadly you’ll have to use some scripting languages to accomodate that as mentioned in a previous answer. Maybe someone has created that already. I would check maybe Reddit or GitHub issues for stuff like that @RokeJulianLockhart

Answer (score 0):

Did you already look into the path of where the extensions are saved?
The extensions are stored under `%USER%\.vscode\extensions`. Deleting that gets rid of them.

- For Linux/MAC: `~/.vscode/extensions`
- For Windows: `%USER%\\.vscode\extensions` (or) `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`

If you want to delete them from the console, you can do that by:

**Mac/Linux**

```
rm -rf ~/.vscode/extensions
```

**Windows**

```
rmdir %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions /s
```

Answer (score 0):

My installation (Visual Studio Code 1.82.0 on MacOS 13.5.1) gives a way to disable a specific extension from the command line.

```
$ code --help

...

Usage: code [options][paths...]

...

  --disable-extension <ext-id>    Disable the provided extension. This option is not persisted and is effective only when the command opens a new window.
```

For example `code --disable-extension ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh` disables the ssh extension (tested).

Comment: Yes, and this *only* disables the extension for the duration of that specific VS Code instance. If you run `code` after it, the extension is enabled again. For posterity, here's the (unclear) release notes for this feature: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_disabling-extensions-from-command-line