# Why is code getting deleted on save (commad + s)?

Tags: typescript, tsx

I'm using VS Code as my IDE and this morning I noticed that when I hit command + s some code gets deleted. Specifically this from my index.tsx file:

```
import { Dialog, Disclosure, Transition } from '@headlessui/react';
import { InformationCircleIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';
```

Has anyone experienced something similar? I tried deleting the Prettier and Eslint plugins and nothings changed.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was this line of code in my settings.json file. I deleted it and that solved it:

```
"files.associations": {
  "*.tsx": "typescript"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently, it was an extension doing cleanup after I put in an early return statement (for testing stuff).  The extension very helpfully thought the code it was removing wasn't used.

Try running VS Code with extensions disabled and see if it persists, that will at least narrow down your suspects: [Disable extensions in VScode from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63158004/disable-extensions-in-vscode-from-command-line)

Comment: This didn't work. I think it's some kind of typo in my code base. If I figure it out I'll post it here. 

Thanks for commenting @frozenkiwi !